# Grails: how to use jQuery & ajax to send data to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I am trying to post a review for an event using ajax to avoid the page reload. This is my form for posting the review.

```
<g:form >
 <g:textArea class="form-control" id="review" name="comment" value="${review?.comment}"></g:textArea>

 <span class="star-rating star-5">
     <g:radio name="rating" id="rating-1" value="1"/><i></i>
     <g:radio name="rating" id="rating-2" value="2"/><i></i>
     <g:radio name="rating" id="rating-3" value="3"/><i></i>
     <g:radio name="rating" id="rating-4" value="4"/><i></i>
     <g:radio name="rating" id="rating-5" value="5"/><i></i>
 </span>
 ...
 <input type="submit" id="comment-ajax"/>
```

My ajax:

```
  $( "#comment-ajax" ).click( function (){
    var eventID = document.getElementById('eventId').innerText;

      $.ajax( {
          url: "${createLink(controller:'review',action:'saveReview')}",
          type: "POST",
          data: { comment: $('.review-textarea').val(), rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(), event:eventID  },

          success: function() {
             alert("success");
          },
          error: function() {
             alert("fail");
          }
      } );
  });
```

ReviewController:

```
def saveReview(Review review) 
{
    User user = User.get(session.user.id)
    def comment = review?.comment
    def rating = review?.rating

    review.save flush:true
}
```

Review domain:

```
class Review {

String comment
int rating

static belongsTo = [event:Event, user:User]
```

The success alert is appearing, but no data is being inserted into my database.

Comment: Try adding failOnError to your save `review.save flush:true, failOnError: true`

Comment: Right, that gave me an error message https://i.gyazo.com/dedbe2c88d03b15cbfddcbee5da2e77f.png

Comment: Try changing saveReview to `def saveReview() { new Review( user: User.get(session.user.id) comment: params.comment rating: params.rating ).save( failOnError: true, flush: true ) }`

Comment: No luck with that either https://i.gyazo.com/5185504afaa234c259590554d3652383.png

Comment: I did a grails clean and it's the same error, except as No such property Review for class ReviewController

Answer (score 2):

A noddy example using some Grails stuff.

All were doing below is updating a div upon success failure with some bootstrap styling and a message, we could also pass some data back from the action and do something with this if need be.

The javascript is invoked when the button with ID 'save' is clicked. You'll see save is prefixed with # meaning the DOM element with identifier, if an element is prefixed with a period . it means the element(s) with CSS class, read more about selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

You can pass back data to the controller using the data section, in the example below we're passing back all the elements of the form with ID eventForm using [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), so you'll get 'eventName' and 'eventDescription' off the params in the controller as these are the 2 inputs in our form

In your example you're trying to get the username from something in the gsp, I would get this in the controller from springSecurityService.

gsp:

```
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $( "#save" ).click( function ( event ){
                $.ajax( {
                    url: "${g.createLink( controller: 'review', action:'saveAjax')}",
                    type: "post",
                    data:  $( '#eventForm' ).serialize(),
                    success: function() {
                        $( "#resultDiv" ).addClass( 'alert alert-info' ).append( 'Successfully saved event' )
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        $( "#resultDiv" ).addClass( 'alert alert-danger' ).append( 'Error saving event' )
                    }
                } );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="resultDiv"></div>

<g:form id="eventForm" name="eventForm">
    Event name: <input type="text" id="eventName" name="eventName" value="${params.eventName}" />
    Event description: <input type="text" id="eventDescription" name="eventDescription" value="${params.eventDescription}" />
    <button type="button" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
</g:form>

</body>
```

ReviewController:

```
def saveAjax() {
    def eventName = params.eventName
    def eventDescription = params.eventDescription

}
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your code just to get my head around ajax a bit but I receive a status 500 error upon clicking save. I tried this from both my event and review show pages but experienced the same outcome

Comment: Note I have used an action named saveAjax rather than save

Comment: I've realised that I am to do the ajax code in the actual gsp and not in an external js file

Comment: Keep in gsp, it's fired in response to click on element with ID named save

Comment: I'm still stuck with this if you'd be able to help; I've updated my original question. I am getting into my controller action, the issue is definitely with the parameters and data, unsure how to pass them correctly

Comment: Updated example

Comment: Updated my q slightly. This is the error I am experiencing https://i.gyazo.com/c341193a53487017d4aa829da6f88933.png

Comment: Take Review argument out of saveReview action and create a new Review object with params.review

Comment: That results in: No such property: review for class ReviewController

Comment: If you do println params in your controller what do you see?

Comment: Update on this; I got an ajax function working for something very similar, but for this review function it is still not working. When I am running the function it goes into success, but the data is not being saved into my database. If I println comment, rating, user - it shows them all in my command prompt. I have updated my original question now, as I said this code structure worked for another function, so there has to be something small wrong with this one, hopefully you can spot it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/YourController/YourAction",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3 },
            success: function (json) {

            }
        });
```

In your Action, you return a Json, like this:

```
return Json(new { success = true, message = "Message"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or something smart, like this, where your controls have the class 'form-control'. This is something similar of a form.serialize(), but here you can customize the format of the data.

```
var selector = 'input.form-control, select.form-control, input[type="hidden"], textarea.form-control'

var formData = {};

$(selector).each(function () {
    var value = '';
    if ($(this).attr("type") == "checkbox") {
        value = $(this).attr("checked") == "checked";
    }
    else if ($(this).attr("type") == "radio") {
        if (formData[$(this).attr('id')] == undefined) {
            value = $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + ":checked").val();
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    else {
        value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    }

    formData[$(this).attr('id')] = value;
});

$.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/YourController/YourAction",
        data: formData,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (json) {

                }
});
```

If you have any quest, just ask =)